# Describe the following group: $\mathbb{Z_{60}^x}$, as a direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The problem in questions asks to describe $\mathbb{Z_{60}^x}$ as a direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order.

The Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups is not allowed in this question.

I would really appreciate it if someone could provide a detailed explanation as I'm kind of lost on how to do this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the fact that elements of $\mathbb Z_{60}^x$ are those that are relatively prime to 60.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you at least tell us the order of this group?

Comment: The order of the group in this particular case would be the number of integers lower than 60 which are relatively prime to it, so 50, no?

Comment: Yes. But it's not $50$. How did you get it?

Comment: This is probably going to sound quite stupid but I counted the factors of 60 (10 by my count) and then subtracted that number from 60.

Comment: Aha. Not a bad thought. However, not only the divisors of $60$ are excluded, but also any number who has any common prime factor with $60$, in particular an even number can't be relatively prime to $60$, so $|\Bbb Z_{60}^\times|<30$. By the way, you can write it up by hand. Work on the representative set $\{-29,-28,\dots,-1,0,1,2,\dots,29,30\}$ so it's just half the work:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76294/discussion-between-mathmaniac-and-berci).

Comment: Well on the one hand if gcd(a,60) = 1 then we have $na m60 = 1$ for some integers $m, n.$ Taking this identity mod 60 gives us that $n=a^{-1}.$ So $a$ is a unit mod 60. On the other hand if $\gcd(a, 60) = d$ then there is a $0 \neq m$ so that $am$ is $0$ mod $60.$ But then $a$ can’t be a unit mod 60, since this would imply $m=0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In such cases the structure is simplest to understand using a computer algebra program like [sage](http://www.sagemath.org). The code is self-explanatory, uses pure mathematical terminology:

```
sage: R = IntegerModRing(60)
sage: R
Ring of integers modulo 60
sage: G = R.unit_group()
sage: G.order()
16
sage: euler_phi(60)
16
sage: G
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C2 x C2 x C4
sage: [ R(x) for x in G.gens() ]
[31, 41, 37]
```

Above we have defined the ring $R=\mathbb Z/60$, considered its group of units, $G=R^\times$, asked for its order, structure, and generators.

To explain this humanly, we may proceed as follows. We have a ring map
$$
\mathbb Z/60\to(\mathbb Z/4)\times(\mathbb Z/3)\times(\mathbb Z/5)\ ,
$$
where on the right side we take operations on components.

The map is given by 
$$
x\text{ mod }60
\to(\
x\text{ mod }4
\ ,\ 
x\text{ mod }3
\ ,\ 
x\text{ mod }5
\ )\ .
$$

It is a ring homomorphism, and a bijection of sets.
So it is a ring isomorphism. A unit in the ring on the R.H.S is a triple of units in the component rings. For these it is simple to exhibit the units. Then we have only to lift generators, which are $(3,1,1)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(1,1,2)$.

Lifting $(3,1,1)$: We search for a $k$ which is $3$ mod $4$, and $1$ mod both $3,5$. So it is $1$ mod $15$. Possible chances are $1,16,31,46$. We pick the $31$ which is $3$ mod $4$.

Lifting $(1,2,1)$. The lift is $1$ mod $4$ and $5$, so it is $1$ mod $20$, possible chances are $1,21,41$, and we pick $41$, which is the wanted $2$ modulo $3$.

Lifting $(1,1,2)$. The lift is $1$ mod $4$ and $3$, so it is $1$ mod $12$, possible chances are $1,13,25,37,49$, and we pick $37$, which is the wanted $2$ modulo $5$.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use the Chinese remainder theorem, then
$$\mathbb Z_{60} \cong \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{5}$$
as rings and so
$$\mathbb Z_{60}^\times \cong \mathbb Z_{4}^\times \times \mathbb Z_{3}^\times \times \mathbb Z_{5}^\times \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_4$$